# PrimeFaces Captcha insider h:form

Tags: forms, primefaces, submit, captcha

I'm trying to use the Primefaces captcha control in a Liferay portlet.

I have the following code:

```
<h:form>
   ....
   <p:captcha id="captcha" requiredMessage="Debe ingresar el captcha"/>
   <p:commandButton value="Send" actionListener="#{registrationPymeViewEdit.onSend}" ajax="false" />
</h:form>
```

And in my web.xml I configured the public and private keys like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.PRIVATE_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
    <param-value>MY_PRIVATE_KEY</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.PUBLIC_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
    <param-value>MY_PUBLIC_KEY</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The problem that I'm having is that the form is not being submited, it never executes the "onSend" method of my bean. If I remove the captcha then the method of the bean executes ok.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I assuming that you do not have any errors on your server log. 
Try to use action instead of an actionlistener with the appropriate action method.